# Microsofi .NET framework Windows 10 not seen by several programs atopping installation

Tags: windows-10, .net-framework

Suddenly any attempt to install a program that uses the .net framework has stopped with a message telling me the program needs .net. I tried the repair options from Microsoft but no joy.

I downloaded an install version but it tells me it is installed and aborts.

I am completely stumped.

Help - please!

Comment: You could find the .net framework in Control Panel. Uninstall it. Download required .net framework from official website to reinstall. If the issue still insists, I consider that you need a Windows 10 media to repair or install.

Comment: You can't uninstall it - just turn it off. n the ideal world I would uninstall it completely and then reinstall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found out the problem, no thanks to Microsoft.

I tried the turn on\turn off many times. I downloaded and ran the NetFxRepairTool various times but it was all a failure.

I spent hours searching the internet to no avail. All the advice was the same.

I then found there was a program called netfx_setupverifier which I ran and my analysis of .net 4 showed a problem with the registry which the other programs failed to find or repair.

The HKLM\software\microsoft.NETFramework\InstallRoot was set to c:\windows\microsoft.NET\framework.

This piece of software pointed out it should be pointing to c:\windows\microsoft.NET\framework64

So I amended the key and problem solved instantly.

Come on Microsoft - you should know this.